# Is there a way to define a default Tab Title on ConEmu?

Tags: conemu

When a new console is created in ConEmu, its tab is named `ConEmu version [processorArchitecture]` (e.g. `ConEmu 130722 [64]`), unless created using the `-cur-console:t:TabName` command-line argument.

I tried looking in the Settings dialog, but I couldn't find any way to specify a default title for new tabs, if they are created, for example, by running "cmd.exe" from the Windows Run dialog (and, of course, having the *Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications* setting turned on).

Is there any way of setting this? Maybe through the registry, or via some undocumented setting or option?

---

**EDIT:** I found a possible way -- setting it on the *Tab templates*, in the *Features\Tabs* setup page.

This won't actually set the default Tab Title (i.e., if I use "%s" on the template, I'll still get the default title I mentioned above), but it will cause the Tab button to show whatever was set in the template, which was the original intent.

Comment: What do you want to see in default tab name?

Comment: Nothing specific... something like "Console", for example. It would be interesting to be able to customize that default name somewhere in the Settings, though.

Comment: Are you sure this problem exist in current Preview and Alpha builds? If so, run `ConEmu /log`, reproduce the problem with tab title, make screenshot and attach screenshot and produced log files.

Comment: I've been using the workaround I mentioned in my edit, so I haven't really tested beyond that. And I didn't think it was a problem or a bug to begin with, just a "nice-to-have" feature. I'd mark this question as answered if there were any answers to it, but there aren't... :)

Comment: That is looks like a bug, actually. Or I've misunderstand you. "ConEmu version" may be displayed during initialization only. After that, it changes to starting command line. By design. That is why I asked about screenshot and log.

Comment: I tried running ConEmu with logging, but something very strange happened: if I simply run ConEmu, I get the "ConEmu _version_ [_processorArchitecture_]" title on the tabs; however, using the `ConEmu /log` command-line, the tabs correctly show the path to `cmd.exe`. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/yfnnlIs.png) anyway.

Comment: Really strange. Can you describe how do you start these two tabs? Anyway, logs may help. Also, if you can create memory dumps of ConEmu64 and ConEmuC64 processes (when tab title bug appears), and send them via dropbox (for example), that would be great.

Comment: I start the tabs by using the "Create new «cmd.exe» console" hotkey (`Ctrl+T` in my current config). If I start the tab with `Win+W`, the title shows the path to `cmd.exe`, however. I've managed to reproduce the issue in one tab while running `ConEmu64 /log`, so I've put everything together (full memory dumps for ConEmu64 and ConEmu64C and the logs) [here](http://dropcanvas.com/eyhcn), in a 7-Zip file. Let me know if the file disappears before you can get it, and I'll upload it to a more reliable location. :D